# Query running slow after upgrade to Sql Server 2008 R2 from Sql Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am seeing strange behaviour after recent Sql server upgrade to 2008 r2 from Sql server 2005.
Before upgrade below query was running in subsecond but now after upgrade it takes 10 seconds .Both table have millions of rows..

There is index on nullable column colB in model table . Below query is obviously doing index scan as there is scalar function isnull being used in Join clause..

```
 select distinct a.colA
             from ptransaction a
             inner join model b on ISNULL(b.colB,0) = a.colB
             where a.transid = 234
```

I don't have any pre-upgrade plan info but this query never ran for more than 1 second..So not sure if something changed in optimizer behaviour in Sql server 2008 which causes it to run slow.

I know alternate solution but don't want to modify schema in hurry..I know I can convert colB in model as notnull to fix this. Other solution is to create indexed computed column which would fix this problem. Schema changes in our env is not easy so want to explore if Sql guru's here have some idea or some other solution which won't require schema change.
I can't still understand how optimizer or overall sql server upgrade can make this query worse.
Any help appreciated.

NJ

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, if there are many records ISNULL slows down the query.

Try this code, the result is the same, but I tend to get best performance:

```
(b.colB is not null and b.colB = a.colB ) OR (b.colB is null and a.colB = 0)
```

Comment: Nah..Still doing Index scan and same performance..I get some boost by removing parallelism but nothing significant..Guess keep looking into improving it..